# rearrange tikz dashed rectangle blocks

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I have the following tikz code:

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
    chains,
    decorations.markings,
    shadows, shapes.arrows,shapes, fit}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
sum/.style      = {draw, circle, node distance = 2cm}, % Adder
input/.style    = {coordinate}, % Input
output/.style   = {coordinate}, % Output
block/.style = { draw,
              thick,
              rectangle,
              minimum height = 2em,
              fill=white,
              align=center
},
wide block/.style = {
              block,
              minimum height = 3em,
              text width=2.5cm,
              minimum width = 8em,
},
dotted_block/.style={draw=black!20!white, line width=1pt, dash pattern=on 1pt off 4pt on 6pt off 4pt,
            inner sep=6mm, rectangle, rounded corners}
}
\newcommand{\suma}{\Large$+$}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, thick, node distance=2cm, >=triangle 45]
\draw
node at (0,0){}
node [input, name=input1] {} 
node [align=center, wide block, right = 1cm of input1] (inte2) {IEEE1}
node [align=center, wide block, right = 1cm of inte2] (inte3) {IEEE2}
node [align=center, wide block, right = 1cm of inte3] (inte4) {IEEE3}
node [sum, right = 1cm of inte4] (suma1) {\suma}
node [input, name=input2, above = 1cm of suma1] {} 
node [output, name=output1, right = 1cm of suma1] {};
\node [align=center, wide block, right = 0.5cm of output1] (glamor) {glamor};
\node[wide block, right = 15mm of glamor] (trainer) {trainer};
\node[block, below=10mm of glamor](M){giga};
\node[block, below=10mm of trainer](L){mn};
\node [dotted_block, fit = (inte2) (inte3)] (aa) {};
\node [dotted_block, fit = (inte4) (suma1)] (aa2) {};
\node [dotted_block, fit = (glamor) (trainer) (L) (M)] (aa3) {};

\node at (aa.north) [above, inner sep=3mm] {T1};
\node at (aa2.north) [above, inner sep=3mm] {T2};
\node at (aa3.north) [above, inner sep=3mm] {T3};

\draw[->](input1) -- node {kmm}(inte2);
\draw[->](inte2) -- node {kdd}(inte3);
\draw[->](inte3) -- node {dx}(inte4);
\draw[->](inte4) -- node {msg}(suma1);
\draw[->](input2) -- node {taco} (suma1);
\draw[<-](glamor.west) --node[above]{$y$} ++(-1.5,0);
\draw[->](glamor) -- node {dol} (trainer);
\draw[->](trainer.east) -- node[name=y]{kmm} ++ (2,0);
\draw[->,rounded corners](trainer.east) -- ++(1,0) |- (L);
\draw[->](L)--(M);
\draw[<-, rounded corners]([yshift=1mm]glamor.south west) 
       -- ++(-1,0) |- (M.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which created the following figure:
[image: Figure]

How can I arrange the dashed rectangles T1, T2 and T3 to be symmetric as possible and contain all the blocks and arrows without overlaps, as there is now for T1 and T2? T3 should surround all the arrows that are currently outside.

The output should be like:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `inner xsep`.

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
    chains,
    decorations.markings,
    shadows, shapes.arrows,shapes, fit}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
sum/.style      = {draw, circle, node distance = 2cm}, % Adder
input/.style    = {coordinate}, % Input
output/.style   = {coordinate}, % Output
block/.style = { draw,
              thick,
              rectangle,
              minimum height = 2em,
              fill=white,
              align=center
},
wide block/.style = {
              block,
              minimum height = 3em,
              text width=2.5cm,
              minimum width = 8em,
},
dotted_block/.style={draw=black!20!white, line width=1pt, dash pattern=on 1pt off 4pt on 6pt off 4pt,
            inner ysep=6mm,inner xsep=3mm, rectangle, rounded corners}
}
\newcommand{\suma}{\Large$+$}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, thick, node distance=2cm, >=triangle 45]
\draw
node at (0,0){}
node [input, name=input1] {} 
node [align=center, wide block, right = 1cm of input1] (inte2) {IEEE1}
node [align=center, wide block, right = 1cm of inte2] (inte3) {IEEE2}
node [align=center, wide block, right = 1cm of inte3] (inte4) {IEEE3}
node [sum, right = 1cm of inte4] (suma1) {\suma}
node [input, name=input2, above = 1cm of suma1] {} 
node [output, name=output1, right = 1cm of suma1] {};
\node [align=center, wide block, right = 0.5cm of output1] (glamor) {glamor};
\node[wide block, right = 15mm of glamor] (trainer) {trainer};
\node[block, below=10mm of glamor](M){giga};
\node[block, below=10mm of trainer](L){mn};
\node [dotted_block, fit = (inte2) (inte3)] (aa) {};
\node [dotted_block, fit = (inte4) (suma1)] (aa2) {};
\node [dotted_block, fit = (glamor) (trainer) (L) (M)] (aa3) {};

\node at (aa.north) [above, inner sep=3mm] {T1};
\node at (aa2.north) [above, inner sep=3mm] {T2};
\node at (aa3.north) [above, inner sep=3mm] {T3};

\draw[->](input1) -- node {kmm}(inte2);
\draw[->](inte2) -- node {kdd}(inte3);
\draw[->](inte3) -- node {dx}(inte4);
\draw[->](inte4) -- node {msg}(suma1);
\draw[->](input2) -- node {taco} (suma1);
\draw[<-](glamor.west) --node[above]{$y$} ++(-1.5,0);
\draw[->](glamor) -- node {dol} (trainer);
\draw[->](trainer.east) -- node[name=y]{kmm} ++ (2,0);
\draw[->,rounded corners](trainer.east) -- ++(1,0) |- (L);
\draw[->](L)--(M);
\draw[<-, rounded corners]([yshift=1mm]glamor.south west) 
       -- ++(-1,0) |- (M.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is another version with individual `inner xsep`s and an `xshift`.

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
    chains,
    decorations.markings,
    shadows, shapes.arrows,shapes, fit}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
sum/.style      = {draw, circle, node distance = 2cm}, % Adder
input/.style    = {coordinate}, % Input
output/.style   = {coordinate}, % Output
block/.style = { draw,
              thick,
              rectangle,
              minimum height = 2em,
              fill=white,
              align=center
},
wide block/.style = {
              block,
              minimum height = 3em,
              text width=2.5cm,
              minimum width = 8em,
},
dotted_block/.style={draw=black!20!white, line width=1pt, dash pattern=on 1pt off 4pt on 6pt off 4pt,
            inner ysep=6mm,inner xsep=4mm, rectangle, rounded corners}
}
\newcommand{\suma}{\Large$+$}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, thick, node distance=2cm, >=triangle 45]
\draw
node at (0,0){}
node [input, name=input1] {} 
node [align=center, wide block, right = 1cm of input1] (inte2) {IEEE1}
node [align=center, wide block, right = 1cm of inte2] (inte3) {IEEE2}
node [align=center, wide block, right = 1cm of inte3] (inte4) {IEEE3}
node [sum, right = 1cm of inte4] (suma1) {\suma}
node [input, name=input2, above = 1cm of suma1] {} 
node [output, name=output1, right = 1cm of suma1] {};
\node [align=center, wide block, right = 0.5cm of output1] (glamor) {glamor};
\node[wide block, right = 15mm of glamor] (trainer) {trainer};
\node[block, below=10mm of glamor](M){giga};
\node[block, below=10mm of trainer](L){mn};
\node [dotted_block, fit = (inte2) (inte3)] (aa) {};
\node [dotted_block, fit = (inte4) (suma1)] (aa2) {};
\node [dotted_block, fit = (glamor) (trainer) (L) (M),inner xsep=9mm,xshift=4mm] (aa3) {};

\node at (aa.north) [above, inner sep=3mm] {T1};
\node at (aa2.north) [above, inner sep=3mm] {T2};
\node at (aa3.north) [above, inner sep=3mm] {T3};

\draw[->](input1) -- node {kmm}(inte2);
\draw[->](inte2) -- node {kdd}(inte3);
\draw[->](inte3) -- node {dx}(inte4);
\draw[->](inte4) -- node {msg}(suma1);
\draw[->](input2) -- node {taco} (suma1);
\draw[<-](glamor.west) --node[above]{$y$} ++(-1.5,0);
\draw[->](glamor) -- node {dol} (trainer);
\draw[->](trainer.east) -- node[name=y]{kmm} ++ (2,0);
\draw[->,rounded corners](trainer.east) -- ++(1,0) |- (L);
\draw[->](L)--(M);
\draw[<-, rounded corners]([yshift=1mm]glamor.south west) 
       -- ++(-1,0) |- (M.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another possibility is to use some auxiliary nodes as landmarks and fit these.

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
    chains,
    decorations.markings,
    shadows, shapes.arrows,shapes, fit}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
sum/.style      = {draw, circle, node distance = 2cm}, % Adder
input/.style    = {coordinate}, % Input
output/.style   = {coordinate}, % Output
block/.style = { draw,
              thick,
              rectangle,
              minimum height = 2em,
              fill=white,
              align=center
},
wide block/.style = {
              block,
              minimum height = 3em,
              text width=2.5cm,
              minimum width = 8em,
},
dotted_block/.style={draw=black!20!white, line width=1pt, dash pattern=on 1pt off 4pt on 6pt off 4pt,
            inner ysep=6mm,inner xsep=1mm, rectangle, rounded corners}
}
\newcommand{\suma}{\Large$+$}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, thick, node distance=2cm, >=triangle 45]
\draw
node at (0,0){}
node [input, name=input1] {} 
node [align=center, wide block, right = 1cm of input1] (inte2) {IEEE1}
node [align=center, wide block, right = 1cm of inte2] (inte3) {IEEE2}
node [align=center, wide block, right = 1cm of inte3] (inte4) {IEEE3}
node [sum, right = 1cm of inte4] (suma1) {\suma}
node [input, name=input2, above = 1cm of suma1] {} 
node [output, name=output1, right = 1cm of suma1] {};
\node [align=center, wide block, right = 0.5cm of output1] (glamor) {glamor};
\node[wide block, right = 15mm of glamor] (trainer) {trainer};
\node[block, below=10mm of glamor](M){giga};
\node[block, below=10mm of trainer](L){mn};


\draw[->](input1) -- node (kmm1) {kmm}(inte2);
\draw[->](inte2) -- node {kdd}(inte3);
\draw[->](inte3) -- node (dx) {dx}(inte4);
\draw[->](inte4) -- node {msg}(suma1);
\draw[->](input2) -- node {taco} (suma1);
\draw[<-](glamor.west) --node[above]{$y$} ++(-1.5,0);
\draw[->](glamor) -- node {dol} (trainer);
\draw[->](trainer.east) -- node[name=y]{kmm} ++ (2,0);
\draw[->,rounded corners](trainer.east) -- ++(1,0) |- (L);
\draw[->](L)--(M);
\draw[<-, rounded corners]([yshift=1mm]glamor.south west) 
       -- ++(-1,0) coordinate[left=1mm](aux) |- (M.west);

\node [dotted_block, fit =(kmm1.center) (inte2) (inte3) (dx.west)] (aa) {};
\node [dotted_block, fit = (inte4) (suma1) (dx.east)] (aa2) {};
\node [dotted_block, fit = (glamor) (trainer) (L) (M) (y) (aux)] (aa3) {};
\node at (aa.north) [above, inner sep=3mm] {T1};
\node at (aa2.north) [above, inner sep=3mm] {T2};
\node at (aa3.north) [above, inner sep=3mm] {T3};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I make the T3 dashed lines to surround also the arrows?

Comment: @Codevan Which arrows? Do you want to also fit the arrow on the right or the complete arrow going from giga to glamore?

Comment: Both that you mentioned, and also align T1 and T2 to have the same size as T3.

Comment: @Codevan Do you want both arrows completely in the dashed box?

Comment: Yes, exactly. All the arrows should be contained in the box

Comment: @Codevan I added an option.

Comment: But the arrow from giga to glamor is still outside of T3.

Comment: @Codevan Yes, maybe, but I did not interpret your request in that way, However, with the methods used you can extend and move the fit wherever. It is a bit cumbersome to get not 100 % clear instructions just learn that you wanted something different. May I suggest that you use `xshift` and `inner xsep` to get what you want? Or draw a sketch and upload the screenshot.

Comment: Done, I edited the post and you can see the desired output. Thanks!

Comment: @Codevan I added an alternative that does not require you to tune `xshift`s.